# VisualForce - rendering two boolean fields

Tags: visualforce, controller, rendered

I'm trying to create a condition on a VF page to show me a field only if the two conditions are met. (I.e. I want to use the 'rendered' attribute twice)

Here is my code:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pa.Permanent_User_ID_Collection__c}" 
rendered="{!!DRD_Submited + !recordTypeIsPPDetect == 'Platform_Detect'}"/>
```

And this is the error I get:

"Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Boolean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you should use boolean methods as `AND(value1, value2, ...)` and `NOT(value1)`

```
<apex:inputField 
    value="{!pa.Permanent_User_ID_Collection__c}" 
    rendered="{!AND(NOT(DRD_Submited), recordTypeIsPPDetect == 'Platform_Detect')}"
/>
```

From design point of view you should not create complex conditions but instead create and use controller property that will isolate field visibility logic of type either `Boolean` (for single field) or `Map<Id, Boolean>` (for collection of records)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pa.Permanent_User_ID_Collection__c}" 
rendered="{!(!DRD_Submited && (recordTypeIsPPDetect == 'Platform_Detect'))}"/>
```

Comment: The ! should only be used at the beginning of the merge field; elsewhere, it acts as a NOT operator, which is probably not the user's intent.

Comment: Tried to execute what you suggested but I get a similar error:
Incorrect parameter type for operator '='. Expected Boolean, received Text

Comment: Please check the updated ans

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions on a rendered attribute, you can also use AND and OR.
Example: *rendered="{!AND(condition_1,condition_2)}"*

For your case, try *rendered="{!DRD_Submited && recordTypeIsPPDetect == 'Platform_Detect'}"*, or *rendered="{!AND(DRD_Submited,recordTypeIsPPDetect == 'Platform_Detect')}"*.

Comment: It actually does compile, however it does not show the field on the VF Page.
The field does exist because if I only use : rendered="{!!DRD_Submited} then the field appears.

Comment: As someone commented in the other answer, multiple "!" signs will operate as negate effect. I have edited my answer to something that should work for you.